# Is Google using DNS records to find websites?

Tags: dns, google-search

I have recently created a subdomain for testing my changes on a live server. Today I have found that Google has indexed nearly a third of this test domain. How did Google find this test subdomain? There are no links to it, there's not wordpress blog (so no pinging of Google when a blog post is made), and it's not been registered in Webmaster Tools.

The only explanation I can think of is Google's free DNS has captured the subdomain address when it propagated around the 'net and is using that to index new websites.

I've added `order deny,allow` to my .htaccess file to block Google (and any visitors who come from the search results), but my question is: Is Google using the DNS records to find new websites? If not, how did Google find my website?

Comment: Yes they are using DNS information.

Comment: "Google's free DNS has captured the subdomain address when it propagated around the 'net "  the DNS does not work exactly like this, it is not top down. Anyway, technically, they can look at all DNS queries they get and infer new domains from that. THey could also, like anyone, download the list of all domain names in gTLD, daily, and use it. THere are a myriad other ways to find domains. Do you use Chrome? Any antivirus or plugin to protect you against phishing or scams ? Or Skype? All of these tools, and many more, are known to "phone home" and collect and forward DNS names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google finds websites lots of different ways. They definitely don't wait for a webmaster to submit the site to them.

They *could* be, and probably are, using DNS. Also, if anyone with something that reports back to Google (ie analytics if it is installed, possibly Chrome, Google toolbar, etc) visits a URL on that subdomain Google will know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, Google says

> Google DNS is not used in web ranking, data is not shared with 'other
>   parts of google'

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OZe5Hhf8I8

Comment: I'm not asking if Google uses the DNS as a ranking factor, just as a method of locating websites that do not have external links pointing to it.

Comment: I understand you didnt ask whether Google uses its Public DNS in ranking, the post I made contained a quote to give context, in that  : Google doesnt use its dns in web ranking.. and/as data is not shared with other parts of google. (ie - not for ranking, not for indexing and not for discovery)

Answer (score 0):

They are registered to sell domains. I'm sure they use a wide variety of crawling methods including keeping track of currently registered domainscalong with DNS data.